# Filter Last items of Pivot table (vba)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, olap, visible

[SNapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8vZH.png) I have a pivot table that needs to show only the last 13 items (week). Below is teh code i used. However, what ever the Visible status of the item in the pivot, it does not change even forcing it to True/False. Already tried an if/else statement but still Visible state does not change.

Appreciate help on this. Thanks!

```
Sub ShowLastXDays()
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim lLoop As Long
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim lCount As Long
Dim lDays As Long
Dim Count As Long

On Error Resume Next
lDays = 13


' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WeeklyPivot")
' Count = pt.PivotFields("[FTYieldData].[Week].[Week]").PivotItems.Count

  Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WeeklyPivot").PivotFields("[FTYieldData].[Week].[Week]")

        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
            pi.Visible = False  'issue encountered. after False code, pi.VISIBLE value remains TRUE (not skipped)
        Next pi

    With pt.PivotFields("[FTYieldData].[Week].[Week]")
        Count = .PivotItems.Count
        For lLoop = .PivotItems.Count To 1 Step -1
            .PivotItems(lLoop).Visible = True  'issue encountered. after TRUE code, since earlier it was not change to FALSE (no error encountered)
            lCount = lCount + 1
            If lCount = lDays Then Exit For
        Next lLoop
    End With

  On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Did you try Running your using `F8` ? If not can you do that, and see at each step what is being executed and what is being Skipped.

Comment: @Mikku I tried doing that and there is nothing being skipped. infact all lines are being executed. If the items is visible (TRUE), setting it to false with the line above does not make the item hidden and still stay as TRUE.

Comment: This is the Problem I think. Remove the Line `.ClearAllFilters` and try running your code. This line makes all the Items Visible, leaving your previous loop not useful.

Comment: ALready removed it in teh code but still exists for both the TRUE (latter) and FALSE (early part of code)value.

Comment: Error shows on the first code pi.Visible = False. I have added an If statement that only make it FALSE if it is true. However, In the first item, Visible is TRUE even though it is not selected in the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

- `.ClearFilters` in your code makes all the Items Visible at once. So your loop that hides all the items is not in effect any more. After that you are looping to set some of those items to `Visible`, which is not applied as all the items are already visible.
- `On Error Resume Next`. You cannot hide all the items in a Pivot Field, that should give you an Error, at least one item should be visible. So in your 1st Loop you will get an Error.

**Try:**

```
    Sub ShowLastXDays()
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim i As Integer

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WeeklyPivot").RefreshTable
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WeeklyPivot").PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone


        Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WeeklyPivot").PivotFields("[FTYieldData].[Week].[Week]")

        For i = 1 To pf.PivotItems.Count
            If i > pf.PivotItems.Count - 13 Then
                  pf.PivotItems(i).Visible = True
            Else: pf.PivotItems(i).Visible = False
            End If
        Next i

    End Sub
```

**Working:**

[image]

**Note:** Using `On Error Resume Next` is not a good approach as it only skips the error, which is sometimes very confusing while Debugging. Instead you should try to Handle the Errors.

Comment: Hi @mikku, sorry about that, CLearFilters is commented in my code. Thus, it does not really clear all the filters. But, same issue still exists.
 I have also issue on below line, in which I should be setting all items hidden, but the TRUE value still shows even if i forced it to FALSE.
           
     For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
                   pi.Visible = False
                Next pi

Comment: Actually, Remove the `On Error Resume Next` , and run your code. You will recieve an error. Mention that in your question. @kyndelacruz

Comment: Ahh, got it. I just copied the code from the net and revised it with my needed setup. Now I am seeing 'unable to set visible property of the pivot item class'. How should I resolve this?

Comment: @kyndelacruz .. Try the code in the latter part of the answer, if showing the last 13 items is the only motive

Comment: Thanks Mikku. I tried the latter code. However, I am having the same failure on 'Else: pf.PivotItems(i).Visible = False'

Comment: I have tested the code on My Pivot and it works well. See the Working in Ans. Can you share the file, to have a better look ? @kyndelacruz

Comment: The first item is unchecked in pivot yet it still goes through the 'Else: pf.PivotItems(i).Visible = False. I tried clearing the filters to start from first data (all visible) but still same error. BTW, the 'WEEK" field items are in a form of column instead of row. Is that an issue?

Comment: The file where the pivot is connected to an external datamodel with about 75mb file size. Can't seem to share it. File has a lot of data included but this specific worksheet (pivot table) is having issue.

Comment: What does the Error Say ? I am not able to replicate your error, unless i do, i won't be able to solve.

Comment: FIrst item (39 =  pf.PivotItems.Count - 13) should indeed go to Else statement. But still cannot execute the Else: pf.PivotItems(i).Visible = False'. Same error as before 'unable to set visible property of the pivot item class'. RUn time error 1004

Comment: Didn't understand what you meant by first Item ? No Column should't be a problem

Comment: Is it working if the years are in the column section while the values are at the row section? Data in my table needs to be in column section to be used for another macro settings. Currently, this is in manual mode and not part of my macro.

Comment: FIrst item if the list (i.e. 1997 in yours).I just counted it to make sure that it indeed does through the else statement. Unfortunately, i still cant fix the error. :(

Comment: I added an image above for you to look on my pivot.

Comment: @kyndelacruz .. i have added two new lines in the Answer. Can you try the answer one last time.

Comment: Thanks @Mikku. I tried it but getting an error on the 2nd line (Missing items'). Error is Runtime error 1004. Application-defined or object defined error. Not sure what should be defined here.

Comment: Okay .. The only way I see now is if you can share the workbook. If not the Entire Workbook, Just the worksheet with Pivot would be enough to replicate the error

Comment: Thanks. I will try to compress the data. I tried using the code you provide on a simple pivot and yes it is working. DO you think pivot table from a Connection affects the use of the Visible property?

Comment: Not Sure @kyndelacruz ... I have never tried to work on a Pivot that is connected.

Comment: I have checked that there is a different approach for an OLAP pivot versus a normal pivot table. Some codes they used are using array. But, don't have luck yet on how to set it for the last 13 items.

Comment: @kyndelacruz .. You may find some info at this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa140063%28v=office.10%29)